# Show that $\lim\left(\frac{3n+2}{n+1}\right)=3$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

To prove that that $\lim(\frac{3n+2}{n+1})=3$

My working:
Let $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ a natural number $m$ s.t. $n \geq m$, then $x_{n} $ satisfies $| x_{n}-x| \lt \epsilon$.
To show $|(\frac{3n+2}{n+1})-3 | \lt \epsilon $
Simplifying $ |(\frac{3n+2}{n+1})-3 | = |(\frac{3n+2-3n-3}{n+1})   |= |(\frac{-1}{n+1}) |= (\frac{1}{n+1}) \lt \frac{1}{n} $.
Now by Archimedean property $\exists$ a natural number $m$ s.t. $\frac{1}{m} \lt \epsilon $ and $n \geq m $ in definition of convergence of a seq $\implies \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{m} \lt \epsilon \implies \frac{1}{n} \lt \epsilon $.

$\therefore |(\frac{3n+2}{n+1})-3 | \lt \epsilon $ is true.
Hence  $\lim(\frac{3n+2}{n+1})=3$

Comment: Does $n$ tend to infinity? Moreover, which is the question here?

Comment: I must add that $3(n+2) \neq 3n+3$

Comment: @Mike Dass Yes i changed it sorry.

Comment: $\frac{3n+2\color{red}{+1-1}}{n+1}=3 - \frac{1}{n+1}\,$, so if you know (or can prove) that $\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$ then you are done.

Comment: Use ```$$...$$``` for writing big equations and ```\left|``` and ```\right|``` for adjusting the size of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Your working is correct but you have not written final steps properly .You want to use following definition of convergence:
The sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ if $\forall \epsilon >0 $ there exists $ m \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $$|x_n-x| < \epsilon ~ \forall n \geq m.$$
proceeding in the same steps as you, we have shown
$$\left|\frac{3n+2}{n+2}-3\right|<\frac{1}{n}.$$ By Archimedian property there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{m} < \epsilon$. Thus for $m \geq n$, we have $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{m} < \epsilon$. Thus we have proved that
$$|x_n-x| < \epsilon ~ \forall n \geq m.$$ Where $x_n=\frac{3n+2}{n+2} ~ \mbox{and} ~ x=3$. This proves the result.

Comment: Thank you.i wrote my question wrong by mistake, have edited it.

Comment: Personal pet peeve of mine: do not write quantifiers after the statement that is quantified over.